# Context API - multiple providers + React hooks for multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can simplify the React Context API providers without having to wrap my parent component with all those Providers? I have a couple of pages: Home, Blog, Contact, Gallery and About. I have created a Context API Context and Provider for the contact page. Every single Provider has its own unique API which I'm fetching using Axios with React Hooks.

What I am asking is there a way, to keep my code clean and dry not to repeat myself over and over again.

For instance, I would like to have one Context function, which I can use over and over again and only get the API data for one unique Axios API URL.

How can I do this? Copy pasting the same thing.. is not clean.

```
PageContext.js: 

import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { PAGE_CONTACT } from 'constants/import';

export const PageContext = createContext();

export const PageProvider = props => {
    const [contactPage, setContactPage] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(PAGE_CONTACT).then(result => setContactPage(result.data));
    }, []);

    return (
        <PageContext.Provider value={[contactPage, setContactPage]}>
            {props.children}
        </PageContext.Provider>
    );
};

PageProvider.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
        PropTypes.node,
    ]).isRequired,
};
```

Page Contact (component) where I use the Context:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

import { PageContext } from 'pages/context/PageContext';

const Contact = () => {
    const [field] = useContext(PageContext);

    return (
        <section className="contact">
            <div className="page">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                        <h3 className="section__title">{field.page_title}</h3>
                        {ReactHtmlParser(field.page_content)}
                        {field.page_featured_image && (
                            <img src={field.page_featured_image.path} />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default React.memo(Contact);
```

Index.js Wrapped the  with the provider:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { PageProvider } from 'pages/context/PageContext';

// Styles
import 'sass/root.scss';

// Root App
import App from './App';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <PageProvider>
        <App />
    </PageProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: I think adding a provider makes little sense, especially add this only increases based on your additional page count. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting approach, I personally would not use context for your solution.

My reasoning for this is that using a provider implies that you want this `value` prop to be accessible for every react `children` prop (which makes no sense for a contact page).

I can only assume that your contact page will have contents that only that pages requires? If so just doing some think like:

Contact Page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

const Contact = () => {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(PAGE_CONTACT).then(result => {
      // Axios - check success!
      if (result.meta === 200) {
        setPageData(result.data);
      }
    });
    // You should be doing error handling here as well!
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="contact">
      <div className="page">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            {!!pageData ? (
              <>
                <h3 className="section__title">{pageData.page_title}</h3>

                {ReactHtmlParser(pageData.page_content)}

                {pageData.page_featured_image && (
                  <img src={pageData.page_featured_image.path} />
                )}
              </>
            ) : (
              <p>Some loading UI...</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

I would say the key take away here is to question you intent with react context. As adding this to the main component will trigger a re-render of the dom when the value changes.

You may have UX that is not dependant on contact page, e.g. an about page.

Comment: thank you very much. The reason why i didn't do it like this is to keept the code DRY. It's the first time that i am using Context API. Maybe it is better to keep it like this from your example.

Comment: I can see why you down that direction, however sometimes this can lead to over-engineered code. Maybe consider a HOC approach, a component that takes `this.prop.pageId` and fetches the data then returns a render prop. e.g. `<FetchPage pageId={PAGE_CONTACT} />` returns `this.props.children({data, hasError, isLoading})`.

Comment: Highly appreciate ur feedback. I have started working with React 2 months ago so i am experimenting with different approaches to see what works the best, to keep the code DRY, clean and readable. If there is one thing i hate.. components that are 200 lines long. I love structure, and readability that way when i return to my code 4 months later, I am still able to recognize and find what i need to change. So basically, what you are saying is create a Component for All pages and fetch the data based on a unique pageId which is a prop with a axios call? Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you Neil!

Comment: I mean there is nothing wrong with that, bear in mind that if have code splitting you won’t pull down the page data unless you need it. You are keen on DRY code but don’t over engineer the solution. You create a service function that fetched data for you. That would reduce the code, but don’t be naive if you think every developer comes back to code any does not want to make changes 